# Is it possible to disable the OpenApi UI in OpenLiberty in a production environment?

Tags: openapi, open-liberty

I'm wondering whether it's possible to disable the OpenApi UI in OpenLiberty in a production environment? For testing purposes this OpenApi UI is great, but I don't want to expose the API in my production enviroment. So far I haven't found any solutions like a configuration property or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option in the OpenAPI features to disable the UI.

You could remove the OpenAPI feature from your server.xml altogether. That would disable both the UI and the serving of the raw OpenAPI document.

If you need an option just to disable the UI, you should open a [feature request](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement&template=feature_request.md&title=).